# LINQ not equal doesn't work

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a datatable that has only one column and a list of values. I'd like to create a LINQ statement to exclude some values from this datatable. And then use the result as a look up table to pull out data from other datable. Here are my codes.

```
   Dim cs1DT = From row In dt1
   Where row.Field(Of String)(0) <> "BS2" Or row.Field(Of String)(0) <> "BS3"
   Select row
   Order By row Ascending

   For Each s As String In cs1DT.ToString
        Dim dt = From row In dt2.AsEnumerable
                 Where row.Field(Of String)("Q_id").Contains(s)
                 Select row
        If dt.Count > 0 Then ListDT.Add(dt.CopyToDataTable)
    Next
```

It doesn't work. The output includes both values BS2 and BS3. It is even worse. It skips my first two list of values that are at the beginning of the datatable dt2. I can't figure out what is wrong. The values in dt1 match first 3 characters in dt2. Can you please help? Thank you.

Comment: You're using an `Or` logical operator. You need an `And`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `And` logical operator, for sample:

```
Dim cs1DT = (From row In dt1
Where row.Field(Of String)(0) <> "BS2" And row.Field(Of String)(0) <> "BS3"
Order By row Ascending
Select row.Field(Of String)(0)).ToList()

For Each s As String In cs1DT
    Dim dt = From row In dt2.AsEnumerable
             Where row.Field(Of String)("Q_id").Contains(s)
             Select row
    If dt.Count > 0 Then ListDT.Add(dt.CopyToDataTable)
Next
```

Comment: Thanks. I have changed Or to AndAlso, but I got some unexpected results. Let me try to debug LINQ in visual studio (I am new on this) and I will let you know what I get.

Comment: It's strange. When I use Debug -> windows -> Immediate, I got some values from Axx -> Azz, and it stops even before the group of BS1. It supposes to show BS1 group. And those values after BS3 didn't show up (?). When I runs it, it shows BS1, BS2 and BS3 and the rest, BUT it doesn't show the first two group Axx and Azz. I am confused. Can you please show me why?

Comment: Sorry, I added a wrong Debug.Print of a different datatable. But after fixing it, it still shows those BS2 and BS3 groups. I wonder why LINQ can't pull out correct data. Also, the "lookup" dt1 have 3 character value like BS1, but dt2 have full BS100. It shouldn't a problem with the Contains function, right?

Comment: I did some changes. I am not sure what you are trying to do but when you try to use `foreach` in a string, you loop between `chars`. In this case, I change to select the column in the first query and in the second, on the results.

Comment: I modified the codes and replaced AndAlso by And but still doesn't work. It keeps pulling out BS2 and BS3. And it skips the top two groups AM and AP. What I am trying to do is I want to pull out all data from the first table (it has only one column) except BS2 and BS3 and use the result as a lookup table to compare with the second table and pull out all data from the second tables that have matched data with tbl lookup